# Replace matched string with its sub-groups

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics

**I have some DNA sequences to process, they look like:**

```
>KU508975.1 Acalypha australis maturase K (matK) gene, partial cds; chloroplast
TAAATTATGTGTCAGAGCTATTAATACCTTACCCCATCCATCTAGAAAAATGGGTTCAAATTCTTCGATA
TTGGCTGAAAGATCCCTCTTCTTTGCATTTATTACGACTCTTTCTTCATGAATATTGGAATTGGAACTGT
TTTCTTATTCCAAAGAAATCGATTGCTATTTTTACAAAAAGTAATCCAAGATTTTTCTTGTTTCTATATA

>KC747175.1 Achyranthes bidentata bio-material USDA:GRIN:PI613015 maturase K (matK) gene, partial cds; chloroplast
GATATATTAATACCTTACCCCGCTCATCTAGAAATCTTGGTTCAAACTCTCCGATACTGGTTGAAAGATG
CTTCTTCTTTGCATTTATTACGATTCTTTCTTTATGAGTGTCGTAATTGGATTAGTCTTATTACTCCAAA
AAAATCCATTTCCTTTTTGAAAAAAAGGAATCGAAGATTATTCTTGTTCCTATATAATTTCTATGTATGT
```

**I coded a regex in order to detect the title line of each sequence:**

```
(\>)([A-Z]{2}\d{6}\.?\d)\s([a-zA-Z]+\-?[a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+\-?[a-zA-Z]+)\s(.*)\n
```

[image]

[image]

**What function should I use to replace this whole match with its group3 + group4? In addition, I've got 72 matches in one txt file, how can I replace them in one run?**

Comment: I assume there is one unique species per sequence? Or else your output will have duplicate FASTA IDs, which you do not want.

Comment: Yes, every sequence is unique

Comment: Your current regex won't work for lines where Group 3 or 4 contrains a single letter word. Also, `\s` also matches line breaks, and if your title lines are shorter than you assume then `.*` may grab a sequence line by mistake.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for pointing out, though this regex fits my data well. Would you mind giving a more rigorous one?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52292561/3832970) below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regex won't work for lines where Group 3 or 4 contains a single letter word because `[a-zA-Z]+\\-?[a-zA-Z]+` matches 1+ letters,  then an optional hyphen, and then again 1+ letters (that means, there must be at least 2 letters). With `[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?`, you can match 1+ letters followed with an optional sequence of `-` and then 1+ letters.

Also, `\s` also matches line breaks, and if your title lines are shorter than you assume then `.*` may grab a sequence line by mistake.  You may use `\h` or `[ \t]` instead.

Note that `\n` is not necessary at the end of the pattern because `.*` matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars with an ICU regex library (it is used in your current code, `str_replace_all`).

In general, you should only capture with `(...)` what you need to keep, everything else can be just matched. Remove extra capturing parentheses, and it will save some performance.

If you add `(?m)^` at the start, you will make sure you only match `>` that is at the start of a line.

You may use

```
"(?m)^>[A-Z]{2}\\d{6}\\.?\\d\\h+([a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?)\\h+([a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?).*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3LFrVs/1).

Code:

```
Sequence <- str_replace_all(SequenceRaw, 
    "(?m)^>[A-Z]{2}\\d{6}\\.?\\d\\h+([a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?)\\h+([a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?).*", 
    "\\1 \\2")
```

Answer (score 1):

**I figured it out myself, with tidyverse packages:**

```
library(tidyverse)

SequenceRaw <- read_file("PATH OF SEQUENCE FILE\\sequenceraw.fasta") ## e.g. sequenceraw.fasta

Sequence <- str_replace_all(SequenceRaw, 
    "(\\>)([A-Z]{2}\\d{6}\\.?\\d)\\s([a-zA-Z]+\\-?[a-zA-Z]+)\\s([a-zA-Z]+\\-?[a-zA-Z]+)\\s(.*)\\n", 
    ">\\3 \\4\n") ## Keep '>' and add a new line with '\n'

write_file(Sequence, "YOUR PATH\\sequence.fasta")
```

**Here is the result:**

[image]